# Sort Map by multiple fields in value (Map as a value)

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I hava a structure that is a `Map` that contains pairs: `String=>Map`.
Is there a way to sort this Map (root) by multiple values? Example to be clear:

Input:

```
"A" => {name: "John", age: "47"}
"B" => {name: "Sam", age: "60"}
"C" => {name: "Josh", age: "30"}
"D" => {name: "Tom", age: "15"}
"E" => {name: "Josh", age: "31"}
```

Sorted:

```
//group 1
"A" => {name: "John", age: "47"} 
//group2
"C" => {name: "Josh", age: "30"} 
"E" => {name: "Josh", age: "31"} 
//group3
"B" => {name: "Sam", age: "60"} 
//group4
"D" => {name: "Tom", age: "15"}
```

Output map is sorted **first** by `name`, **then** (within sorted groups) by `age`.
I am able to sort by single map value entry, but I can't find an easy(-ish) way to sort by multiple entries (in given order). I can try to split this structure after every sort, apply next level sort and join everything at the end, but I am looking for more fancy solution (if there is one).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `collections.sort` with a `Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>`

Comment: If I understand right you have a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`. It would probably be advantageous to use a custom class instead of your inner map such as `Map<String, Person>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java provides a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which will allow you to specify a comparator in which it will sort your input.

To use the `TreeMap` in a traditional way, you will need to do something like so:

```
private class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person t) {
        if(!this.getName().equals(t.getName()))
            return this.getName().compareTo(t.getName());

        return Integer.compare(this.getAge(), t.getAge());
    }
}

private class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.compareTo(p2);
    }
}

public NewClass()
{
    SortedMap<Person, String> map = new TreeMap<Person, String>(new CustomComparator());

}
```

So basically you would need to swap the key and value pairs. If this is not what you are after, then you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) previous SO questions for more answers.

Comment: Does this make the `Map` implementation specific?

Comment: @ReutSharabani: If you go for `TreeMap` yes, since you will be using a concrete class. If you want to go for interfaces, then you can write your code against a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: I wanted to avoid using separate class, but I guess that's clean and simple. Thanks!